# Extract inner json data xcode with NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

My json response from a URL is:

```
[
 {"status":0,
  "id":"26",
   "content":"See info field for info",
   "time":1347565292761,
    "info": {"id":"26",
    "name":"Ruti",
    "twitterPageFollowers":null,
     "facebookPageLikes":null,
     "activeEmailClients":1}
  }
 ]
```

I need to extract from it the following strings:

```
twitterPageFollowers
facebookPageLikes
activeEmailClients
```

How can I do it?

I tried parsing like this

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil ];
    NSString *returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *jsonData = [returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *response = [json objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *info = [response objectForKey:@"info"];
    NSData *businessInfoString = [info dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *businessInfo =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: businessInfoString
                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error: nil];
```

And the return data is ok, but I get [__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:unrecognized selector sent to instance for the last NSDictionary creation from info field.
What is wrong or what is the shorter way to retrieve the above fields?

Comment: **U-N-R-E-L-A-T-E-D** to Xcode. Retagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve the "info" field using `[response objectForKey:@"info"];`, you already get an `NSDictionary`! (and **NOT** an `NSString`).

That's why when you try to call `dataUsingEncoding:` on this object (that you believed was an `NSString` but is as `NSDictionary`) you get the exception.

There is no need to retrieve the value of `"info"` key then converting it to `NSData` and converting it back a JSONObject, because it is already a JSONObject, namely an `NSDictionary` in your case. Why bother trying to convert it back and forth, whereas **`[response objectForKey:@"info"];` already returns that `businessInfo` dictionary that you expect** at the end of your code?

Comment: Right. I extracted it from the info.